# Ubuntu Server keep logging me as root after mount

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, mount

I keep logging in as `root@mymachinename` and not as my user `mmg@mymachinename` I'm not sure why.

Backstory:
I tried to mount a shared folder following [this guide] (https://gist.github.com/estorgio/0c76e29c0439e683caca694f338d4003) I did manage to link a shared folder but after I rebooted, it auto-logged me as root user!

I tried to search online "why I'm auto logging as root" but didn't find anything. Has anyone else faced this issue before? How can I fix it?

Details:

`Ubuntu Server`

`5.15.0-84-generice #93-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`using: virtual box`

```
~# systemctl status:
State: maintenance
Jobs: 0 queued
Failed: 1 units
```

[full results (I'm unable to copy output text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zklo8.png)

```
~# systemctyl --failed
home-user-shared.mount loaded failed failed /home/user/shared
```

```
~# systemctl -reset-failed
removes it from failed but when I reboot it returns ):
```

if you need any more info let me know
not sure what to do here.

Comment: Logging in where/how? Console, SSH, Desktop, Serial, …?

Comment: I'm on windows host logging in from virtual box program

Comment: I just noticed this message https://imgur.com/2GgdrRT

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

If mount failed you have to comment or remove `shared   /home/<username>/shared vboxsf  defaults    0   0` 
from `/etc/fstab`